# Choosing correct threshold value for classification in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, roc, precision-recall

I am working on an ad's clicked or not on a website classification dataset(a pretty much balanced one). I need to know the correct probability threshold for classifying whether website visitors will click ad or not.

Objective:- Since ads are expensive on the website, we want to make sure ads are displayed only to those who have good chance of converting and unnecessary clicks will only add heavily to our cost.

So now I have to select threshold value in such a way that we have good number of conversions and have low ad clicks which don't convert.

I ran logistic regression (1=ad clicked 0=not clicked) and attached image has data on `accuracy`, `recall`, `precision`, `auc score`, `f1_score` at threshold values 0.4,0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6.

As per my knowledge that threshold value should be selected where f1_score is maximum. However, since we want to minimize ad clicks which don't convert we want to have high precision i.e. as low false positives as possible.

For this dataset the f1 score is max at threshold=0.45, however precision is higher at threshold=0.55 & 0.6. What threshold value should I select given our mentioned objective?

Tried looking for answers on determining correct threshold value but found none very satisfying. searched stackoverflow and web.

```
THRESHOLD=0.4 #0.4 to 0.6 incremented by 0.5

predictions=np.where(classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] > THRESHOLD,1,0)
pd.DataFrame(data=[accuracy_score(Y_test, predictions), recall_score(Y_test, predictions),
                   precision_score(Y_test, predictions), roc_auc_score(Y_test, predictions), f1_score(Y_test,predictions)], 
             index=["accuracy", "recall", "precision", "roc_auc_score",'f1_score'])
```

Correct threshold value

Comment: You'll get the lowest false positive rate with a probability threshold of 1.0. However you won't be showing many ads at all... To do anything more you'll need to determine the cost and benefits of the classifications, as well as the class balance, which is out of scope here and more suited for crossvalidated.SE.

Comment: This is not a *programming* question, and arguably it is not even a statistics/ML one suitable for Cross Validated; as nicely explained in [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/classification-probability-threshold), choosing a threshold is *not* part of the statistics/ML component, but part of the *decision/business* component of your application. No one can tell you if you should choose to maximize the F1-score or the precision, it depends solely & exclusively on *your* business needs (including the *costs* of misclassified samples)...